# How to add entity inside another entity

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am working on .Net Core

This is my mission page. Its releated with two table actually.[image]

In the old tradition you have to fill each table before you pick that data from here

but **what i want is** to add new drivers from here.

[image]

**To be clear**, I can pick two drivers Vin and Jason however if i text here something else and if i press the add mission button It should be added to Drivers table and Missions Table too

I tried:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Mission>>> AddMission(MissionDto request)
{
    var driver = _context.Drivers
    .include(p=>p.Missions)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == request.name)
    ?? new Driver
    {
        Name = request.Name,
        Age = request.Age
        //...
        //...
    };

    var newMission = new Mission
    {
        TimeCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
        MissionId = request.ShipmentId,
    };

    driver.Missions.Add(newMission);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have concerns about new drivers to be added. Is it correct to use this way? Thanks in advance for your advice and help.

Comment: "Is it correct to use this way?" You can use this method to add new drivers, before inserting new Mission and Driver, you can check for the existence of drivers, then adding new ones. But from your code, we can see that for new Driver, we can only set its name, if they have some other required properties, it may not satisfy. In this scenario, you can try to open a popup modal to enter the Driver information, then use JQuery Ajax to call the back-end method to add new Driver, then in the success function, close the popup model and update the selected items in the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add new `Driver` explicitly and `Include` Missions collection:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Mission>>> AddMission(MissionDto request)
{
    var driver = _context.Drivers
        .Include(d => d.Missions)
        .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == request.name);

    if (driver == null)
    {
        driver = new Driver
        {
            Name = request.Name,
            Age = request.Age
            //...
            //...
        };

        _context.Drivers.Add(driver);
    }

    var newMission = new Mission
    {
        TimeCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
        MissionId = request.ShipmentId,
    };

    driver.Missions.Add(newMission);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Mission>>> AddMission(MissionDto request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var driver = new Driver();

    driver = await _context.Drivers
        .Include(driver => driver.Missions)
        .Where(driver => driver.Name == request.Name)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

    var mission = new Mission
    {
        TimeCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
        MissionId = request.ShipmentId,
    };

    if(driver is not null)
    {
         driver.Missions.Add(mission);
        _context.driver.Update(driver)
    }

    if (driver is null)
    {
        driver = new Driver
        {
            Name = request.Name,
            Age = request.Age
            //...
            //...
        };

        driver.Missions.Add(mission);
        await _context.Drivers.AddAsync(driver,cancellationToken);
    }

   
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but i didnt understand what CancellationToken is. What does CancellationToken contain.

Comment: It's not related to problem. it's `Best Practice` and you can read more at [link](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers) @Commodore